# Hightlight the text in RadComboBox when close the menu

Tags: silverlight, telerik, rad-controls

I use RadComboBox in Silverlight. I got the binding data from somewhere. The question is when I click the dropdown arrow to close the menu but the text selected  is not focused or highlighted.

I have `LostFocus`, `DropDownOpened` and `SelectionChanged` events for this RadComboBox. I put the code

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
this.comboBox.Focus();
```

in either of these events.

But the selected text in the drop down menu can not be focused(hightlighted). Maybe it can not be achieved inside its own events?

**EDIT:**

Code:

```
<RadComboBox
Grid.Column="2"
Grid.Row="12"
x:Name="fileLocDropDown"
LostFocus="FileLocDropDown_LostFocus"
KeyDown="FileLocDropDown_KeyDown"
DropDownOpened="FileLocationDropDown_DropDownOpened"
IsEditable="True"
CanAutocompleteSelectItems="True"
IsUpperCase="True"
MaxDropDownHeight="600"
IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
Text="{Binding FileLocCode,Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NullValueConverter},ConverterParameter='Text',NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
MaxLength="3"
SelectionChanged="FileLocDropDown_SelectionChanged"
ItemsSource="{Binding FileLocList}">
<RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightYellow" >
            <TextBlock Margin="4,0,4,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding FileLocCode}" Width="30" />
            <TextBlock Margin="4,0,4,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding FileLocName}" Width="150" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Image:

[image: abc]

Comment: What do you mean by "highlighting" the text? Do you want the text to be selected? (a.k.a. [make it blue](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Mini-Support-Stories-and-Shake-It,-Baby))

Comment: @Martin. Yes, see the image. "ABC" is selected.

Answer (score 0):

On your RadComboBox set the following values:

```
CanAutocompleteSelectItems="True" IsEditable="True"
```

This should give you the behaviour you want, although it does mean that users will be able to enter whatever random text into the input field, so you may need to handle this.

EDIT:
Create a new property in the class that FileLocList contains, which concatenates the FileLocCode and FileLocName strings (with a line break in there I guess if you want to replicate the stackpanel's effect).

Then, get rid of the ItemTemplate and hook up DisplayMemberPath to your new string instead.

Comment: It works for me - could you post the xaml markup defining your RadComboBox?

Comment: It's your ItemTemplate that's stopping it from working.

Create a new property in the class that FileLocList contains, which concatenates the FileLocCode and FileLocName strings (with a line break in there I guess if you want to replicate the stackpanel's effect). 

Then, get rid of the ItemTemplate and hook up DisplayMemberPath to your new string.

Comment: But I need ItemTemplate. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Edited my answer with a suggestion, let me know if that's no good for some reason

Comment: It has two issues. One is the displayed effect is ugly. Two is when I select it, it shows the new string, which concatenates the FileLocCode and FileLocName. I only want FileLocCode. In the selection_changed event I did choose it.